# Python: write CSV column with loop

Tags: python, csv

Using Python, I'd like to create a loop to write text in a CSV file when a row contains text.

The original CSV format is:

```
user_id,    text
0,  
1,  
2,  
3,  sample text
4,  sample text
```

I'm seeking to add another column "text_number" that will insert the string "text_x", with x representing the number of texts in the column. I'd like to iterate this and increase the string's value by +1 for each new text. The final product would look like:

```
user_id,    Text,   text_number
0,      
1,      
2,      
3,  sample text,    text_0
4,  sample text,    text_1
```

With my working code I can insert the header "text_number", but I'm having difficulty in putting together the loop for text_x.

```
import csv

output = list()
with open("test.csv") as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
    for i, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        if i == 0:
            output = [row+["text_number"]]
            continue
        # here's where I'm stuck
            
with open("output2.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",")
    for row in output:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you use `pandas`?

Comment: Yep, comfortable with pandas.

Comment: `"text_x", with x representing the number of texts in the column` what do you mean by number of texts?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Basically, I want the first text for user id 3 to have a value of text_0, user 4 as text_1, and onwards for other texts in the file.

Comment: @DanielHutchinson I have added the answer, check that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find description in comments

```py
# asuming the file
# user_id,text
# 0,  
# 1,  
# 2,  
# 3,sample text
# 4,sample text
# 5, 
# 6,sample text

# import the library
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv').fillna('')

# creating column text_number initializing with ''
df['text_number'] = ''

# getting the index where text is valid
index = df.loc[df['text'].str.strip().astype(bool)].index

# finally creating the column text_number with increment as 0, 1, 2 ...
df.loc[index, 'text_number'] = [f'text_{i}' for i in range(len(index))]

print(df)

# save it to disk
df.to_csv('output2.csv')


#    user_id         text text_number
# 0        0                         
# 1        1                         
# 2        2                         
# 3        3  sample text      text_0
# 4        4  sample text      text_1
# 5        5                         
# 6        6  sample text      text_2
```

Comment: Greatly appreciate the assistance here. This approach worked! One wrinkle, however. Apparently the blank spaces are read as `NaN`, and text numbers are created for those cells as well. Any ideas on how to ignore those?

Comment: so you have blank space also? Now try , see the change `df = pd.read_csv('test.csv').fillna('')` in above code

Comment: Yes, it appears so. No values shows up in Excel, but in running the script it reads as `NaN`.

Comment: That solved it! Many thanks for the assistance, big help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import csv

output = list()
x=0
with open("test.csv") as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
    for i, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        row[1]=row[1].strip()
        if i == 0:
            row.append("text_number")
        else:
            if row[1]=="":
                row.append(" ")
            else:
                row.append(f"text_{x}")
                x+=1
        output.append(row)            
with open("output2.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",")
    for row in output:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

I haven't changed anything in your code, which should be changed. I
am just `adding` `new element` in `row` in `every iteration`. And `append` that every `row` in `output`, for making new `list of row`.

If you are comfortable with `pandas` then you can try this too:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("test.csv")

r=[]
x=0
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df["    text"][i].strip()=="":
        r.append(f" ")
    else:
        r.append(f"text_{x}")
        x+=1

df["text_number"]=r

print(df)
"""
   user_id           text   text_number
0        0                     
1        1                     
2        2                     
3        3    sample text      text_0
4        4    sample text      text_1
"""
pd.to_csv("output2.csv")
```

Here we are making list for `text_number` column.

Comment: Greatly appreciate the assistance here. Both approaches worked! One wrinkle, however. Apparently the blank spaces are read as `NaN`, and text numbers are created for those cells as well. Any ideas on how to ignore those?

Comment: I have edited the answer. I forget to do that my bad

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following modification of your first part:

```
output = list()
with open("test.csv") as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
    output.append(next(csv_reader) + ['text_number'])
    text_no = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row[1].strip():
            row.append(f'text_{text_no}')
            text_no += 1
        output.append(row)
```